# Substitute for Delphi's TFrame in Qt5

Tags: qt, delphi, qt5, c++builder, tframe

What would be the substitute for an *Embarcadero Delphi* **TFrame** in Qt5?

In *Delphi* one can design a *TFrame* like a reusable kind of form, which can be assigned to and instantiated within other controls afterwards.

Comment: I would use a QWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using qt widgets a [Qwidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) or [QFrame](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#details) could be a viable option. In qml an [item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) seems to be the best match